# Enable directory listing on valet installed server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I have installed [valet-linux](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux). It disables browsing other projects that I need by running

```
localhost/project
```

It displays Valet not found.

I tried

```
autoindex on;
```

in both valet and nginx configuration and restarted server. Still I cannot access the project using localhost/project.

I'm currently using following versions:

```
Nginx : 1.14.0 PHP : 7.0 Valet : 2.0.24
```